# Como passar um objeto (instância de uma classe) de MainActivity para outra atividade (MainActivity2) no AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

SuperHeroFeatures é uma classe com todos os atributos de um super-herói, como nome, aniversário, poder e muitas outras coisas. Agora, a instância heroSelected está funcionando, mas não posso transmiti-la para a outra atividade. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Em MainActivtity, tenho uma função que chama:

```
    SuperHeroFeatures heroSelected = superHeroFeaturesList.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("superHeroFeatures", heroSelected);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Em MainActivtity2, tenho uma função que chama:

```java
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    SuperHeroFeatures superHeroFeatures = (SuperHeroFeatures) intent.getSerializableExtra("superHeroFeatures");
    Context context;
    TextView name;
    ImageView imag;

    public MainActivity2(Context context, SuperHeroFeatures superHeroFeatures) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hero_features);
        name= findViewById(R.id.responseView);
```